# whats the maximum number of requests gevent wsgi server handle

Tags: python-3.x, flask, wsgi, gevent

What is the maximum number of requests gevent wsgi can handle. I have a flask application which is served via gevent wsgi server. I am unaware how many requests gevent wsgi will handle per second.

I also wanna know how to introduce threads in gevent wsgi.

My code:

```
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
import os
from gevent.server import _tcp_listener

def run(app, port=8889, listener=None):

    if listener is None:
        listener = ('', port)
        
    http_server = WSGIServer(listener, app )
    http_server.serve_forever()

def main():
    listener = _tcp_listener(('0.0.0.0', '80'))
    run(app, None, listener)
    return 0
```

app is the flask app on another file app.py

Comment: There are a number of settings you can tweak that will affect performance in different scenarios. Maximum throughput will also depend on your system specifications. Your best bet would be to just test it yourself using a performance measurement tool.

Comment: @sytech I dont have latency issues and all as the clients that contact server are in same network. But there will be atleast 100 clients will be there on that network which will contact that server. So I want to know the scalability of the server

Comment: Can't say for sure without knowing exactly what your app does or other characteristics, but so long as you aren't doing anything crazy, 100 users should be trivial for a single server with sufficient resources to handle. gevent won't be the bottleneck -- it can easily handle hundreds of concurrent connections without issue.

Comment: @sytech thanks for ur point. My app is so minimal its just gonna hit an external url, get that response and return that response to the requested client. As u said, is manual threading is not at all needed?. I just wanna know an maximum amount for my documentation. Is flask threaded by default and diesnt require manual thread handling?

Comment: Correct on all points -- no custom threading code needed, production WSGI servers implement this for you, as far as concurrent request handling goes. So long as this "external url" is reasonably responsive, your app shouldn't have any problems with that... but you need to keep in mind how gevent concurrency works and make sure your code doesn't interfere with the gevent event loop.... in any case, it sounds like you have a lot of questions loaded into this one. Maybe consider identifying your individual questions/concerns and researching them and asking separate questions for them if needed.

Comment: @sytech Thanks. I have a simple question still, will it handle atleast 100 clients at a time without thread coding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247866/discussion-between-bharath-s-and-sytech).